# Каким образом рисуется кружок с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript

Интересует не код, а алгоритм, ход решения.

Также интересно, как нарисовать градиент выбора цвета на js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итак, техника рисования ромбиков на js (для рисования кружков нужно взять функцию полукруга, но идея точно такая же):

```
var obj = document.getElementById('container');
var tmp, k = 0, m = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
   if (i > m / 2) k--; else k++;
   tmp = document.createElement('div');
   tmp.width = k + 'px';
   tmp.height = '1px';
   obj.appendChild(tmp);
}
```

А вообще все верно Вам намекают на использование `canvas`, т.к. под IE есть поддержка от гугла, а в адекватных браузерах он и так работает на ура.

Comment: Вот-вот — это тот самый «тупой способ», о котором я говорил :). Только с кружками всё сложнее, увы…

Comment: А все нормальные уже предложили :) Человеку ведь интересно как это происходит, на сколько я понимаю :)

Answer (score 5):

```
function calcPoints(X0, Y0, R, N) {
    var points = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            x = X0 + R*Math.sin(i*2*Math.PI/N);
            y = Y0 + R*Math.cos(i*2*Math.PI/N);
            total[i] = {'x': x,'y': y};
        }
    return points;
}
```

Описание алгоритма:

- определить центр, радиус и количество сегментов,
- пройти в цикле по каждому сегменту:
- рассчитав координаты X и Y для точки по формулам тригонометрии,
- добавив точку в массив,
- отрисовать массив по координатам любым удобным способом, например, используя абсолютное позиционирование (проще - на JQuery).

Comment: как именно отрисовать, используя js, html, css?

Comment: Так, как написано ниже, используя алгоритм, который выше :)

Comment: Идея от Alex Silaev вполне подходит. Только лучше div-ам устанавливать свойства left и top при постоянных width и height.

Answer (score 4):

А может просто применить атрибуты, которые закругляют углы, то есть:

```
border-radius
-webkit-border-radius
-moz-border-radius
```

И ставить радиус равный половине длины/высоты элемента.

Comment: Тоже неплохой вариант. Только его в IE уж точно никак не заставить работать.

Comment: IE9-beta поддерживает border-radius

Comment: Да.. это значит, что лет через десять этот способ можно будет использовать :) Мы еле еле избавляемся от IE6.. слава богу он наконец-то уходит и отпускает нас с миром.. к тому времени, как IE9 будет считаться уже нормой и эта возможность наконец будет доступна, она (возможность) уже не будет никому нужна. К тому времени какие-нибудь SVG+HTML6 начнут завоёвывать мир :)

Answer (score 3):

Тупой способ: рисовать по точкам, создавая что-нибудь вроде `div`'ов.

Правильный способ: использовать `<canvas>` или JS библиотеку, его эмулирующую. [Что такое Canvas](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2009/86.html).

Comment: HTML 5 не трогаем

Comment: Говорю же, «или JS библиотеку, его эмулирующую».

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

Comment: Иного не дано.

Comment: И всё-таки, каким образом рисуются кружки?

Comment: http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/ball.html

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com) — пример рисования круга есть на этой же странице.